# Disable meteor file watching for checking cpu usage

Tags: node.js, meteor

We detected some 7% CPU spikes in idle mode of our meteor apps.

Trying to check if this comes from Meteors file watching.

We tried using the `meteor run --once` and `meteor --production` parameters.

But they hadn't any effect.

Is there a way to turn off file watching?

(In Case `--once` turns it off, what could cause the spikes? We even excluded all our code.)

Comment: The `meteor` command should only be used in development, not in production. In production you should always run the bundle. I assume in development you don't care about intermittent spikes of the cpu to 7%, right?

Comment: What do you mean "run the bundle" ? Yes, in dev env. it would be no problem.

Comment: see `meteor build --help`.

Comment: @ChristianFritz is right, you should "build" your meteor application not run it in dev mode in production!

Comment: Thx- Yes for production we use exactly this.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use the `meteor` command in production. Use `meteor build` to get a production bundle that you can deploy on your production machines. You start it with `node main.js` (but read the README.md first to see which ENV vars need to be set first). The production bundle doesn't watch files.

Comment: Ah yes, we do this already for production. But we still encounter these spikes. The tests i talked about in my Q are in DEV environment.